# WatchKit Extension: Page-based hierarchy for glances

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

There is something confusing in Apple's Programming Guide documentation. While they are illustrating the glances they used a figure that shows a glance represented in a page based navigation.

[image]

But they ended it up saying this.

[image]

The question is, can i have multiple glances in a page based navigation?

The programming guide: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaGlance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you little bit confused with this image.
Glance interface controller like home screen widget (or any else). It could be just in one screen and without any scrolling. Then user could choose best glances (from multiply apps) and then they will be in his watch home screen. This page base navigation at image about multiply glances from multiply apps.

And Apple mean that in you app (current and one) you could have only one glance interface controller that user could chose to be at home screen. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

The image is confusing, but what's happening there is that the multiple "pages" are actually different apps. Each app can have its own glance, and then the user swipes through them just like a paged application, but each app can only contribute one page.